# Should we close older Identify questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

We have [about 25%](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bidentify-this-movie%5D+answers%3A0) of our unanswered questions belonging to [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie), 9 of which were asked over 2 months ago (before March).

I want to close them purely for the fact that they have been sitting there collecting dust.  If anything, I would like to close the ones that are from *unregistered* users (the majority) and leave the ones from active users as still open as well as make this at least a bit of a policy in order to clean up the [somewhat undesireable](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) identify questions.

Note:  This is **not** a plea to make Identify-This-X off-topic but rather a question of community opinion about users that are *extremely unlikely* to visit again.

---

TL;DR

**Should we make it policy to close Identify-this-x questions from *unregistered* users that are more than a month old?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would agree if the unregistered user has not visited the site for a month, and the question is unanswered - or if requests for more detail have been made via comments and are being ignored.

Comment: Honestly I'm ok with closing it a day after details have been asked for if they don't make any updates.  They always have the option to flag for mod attention if they update it.  Maybe I'm too strict.

Comment: @DForck42: Me too - but I think we should give a little more grace time than that.  A lot of people would not flag for moderator attention to reopen a closed question - just go somewhere else.

Comment: How about two days?  ;)

Comment: @DForck42 as strict as I would like to be we should give them some grace period.  We have gotten some great users out of identify questions so a month should be sufficient enough IMO

Comment: @DForck42 actually, how about we meet in the middle: 2 weeks :)

Comment: @tylershads two weeks works for me