# Identify question issue

Tags: discussion, identify

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we close older Identify questions?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380/should-we-close-older-identify-questions)

I suggest that Identify question should be closed if asker is not coming back after months.
For example take this [example](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8096/movie-where-teen-boy-rapes-and-kills-girl-accidentally-and-then-friends-cover). Where three answers are available but user never came back to accept it.

Whats other thinks? I even want to post the close vote but not sure which reason to select.

Comment: Agreed! Valid reason! But the question is what happens to the answerers who took the toil to find it?

Comment: [This is already a policy](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/380/should-we-close-older-identify-questions)

Comment: @TylerShads then what time period is decided for it to delete

Comment: There is no specific timeline - occasionally one of the mods will go back and do this. However questions with answers are usually left to protect the reputation score of people who made genuine efforts to answer the question and got upvotes.

Comment: I usually go through once a month or so and delete anything that has been closed for over a month.  I usually try and make sure to only delete ones that have no value whatsoever, but I'm not perfect.  I also retain ones that are exact duplicates so that they are likely to show up when people search or start asking a question.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate to redirect this discussion so to keep all the information under one post.