# my question was deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28586/49) about a film I am looking for and I logged in today to find that it has vanished.

what happened to it? why was i not notified that it was removed?

how can i recover my deleted question? i spent a lot of time writing it and investigating it, now that it's gone i feel like i've been robbed, how can i get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the relationship between OnlineDevs.com and StackExchange is, but I do know that OnlineDevs.com reposts StackExchange questions (and answers).

So, using a bit of Google, I was able to locate your original question **"Blue ant eater people that turn into flying whales either when they die or for some other reason"** on the OnlineDevs.com site at [this link](http://onlinedevs.com/blue-ant-eater-people-that-turn-into-flying-whales-either-when-they-die-or-for-some-other-reason/).

The full text of your question is available there, along with the answer that had been given (no context in terms of users or anything though).

Comment: If this answer is solely about viewing the original question, then that link is not necessary since [the question here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28586/49) is also readable for him, I have also provided a link to the original question in the meta question. The asker (as well as any 10k user) should be able to view that.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The way he phrased it, sounded like he couldn't find his question text anymore and wanted to recover it (he linked to the question himself too). Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: OnlineDevs is one of many sites that crawls metadata, sucks in the good stuff, and then sprinkles in PPI (Pay Per Impression) ads so they can make money.  Whenever I google an IT question I always avoid any hit from BigResource, which is basically just a clickfarm that runs you in circles, and each link you click on that you think takes you to the answer only contains more links and a bunch of PPI ads.

Comment: Thanks Trish. My original question didn't have a link, someone edited it in for me. I never realised that my posts were being copied onto other sites.

Answer (score 6):

The policy on identification questions is, that they are **eligible for deletion when they don't have any upvoted or accepted answers and remained inactive for 4 weeks**, as described in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417/49). Since this policy has recently been updated as described in [this meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1671/49), there was a recent cleanup session where questions that are thus deletable were acted upon accordingly, [yours](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28586/49) was one of them.

You might feel like having been robbed and I see that you have put much detail into the question, but such are the rules of this site and they are necessary to tackle the long-term negative impact those inactive identification questions have on the site. If however, you have **any new insights or updates to your question** that may provide new possibilities for answering, you can **add them in and it might get undeleted**.

---

However, I wonder why you haven't been notified of the removal. I thought a deleted question would automatically trigger a user notification. If not, then I see why you were surprised. Thanks for bringing this to notice.

Comment: Once my question also got deleted on the same condition and i didn't got any notification.

Comment: The same thing happened to my question (and it was deleted by you, no less!) but it's good to know the reason why.   I also did not see any notification of it having been deleted, and discovered it had been deleted by accident (i did a Google search and found it mentioned in the link but not on the page it linked to; went into Google's cache to find the original question).