# Is there a question penalty for a question that was deleted because it had no answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I believe that I had a question on the site that received one or two upvotes, but no answers that was under the heading of "Identify This Movie." (It was an Americanized version of the Sound of Music, with a widowed father, children, governess, and the other woman.) It appears to have since been deleted.

Normally there is a question penalty when questions are deleted. But to a greater extent than others, this site will delete questions that have no answers. Does the question ban still apply in this case? Do the upvotes mitigate the impact?

Comment: Are there any unclarities about the existing answers that you might want to adress in a comment?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: No, I'm fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no exception to SE's question banning policy on this site. However, you have to really ask *a lot* of inactive ID questions without many other reasonable questions asked among them. So I do not see a big problem with this mechanism being in place, as it was exactly established for the StackOverflow version of identification-only askers originally.

In addition to that, as sepcified in [the respective FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/162011), deleted questions only count against the "bad question" statistics **if they were less than 30 days old at the time of deletion**, which is usually not the case, since the [inactive ID deletion policy](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417/49) only grips after at least 28 days of *inactivity* (*not* creation), and even then they're merely eligible for deletion, to be *possibly* deleted by an explicit manual maintenance action. So even a deleted question will most of the times not count against a possible question ban anyway.

**Update:** As a result of this discussion, we have extended the period for inactive ID questions to become deletable from 4 weeks to 30 days straight.

Comment: Basically, you used the (30-day) exception. That's fair.

Comment: It might be worth changing the inactive ID policy to specifically 30 days to avoid punishing users?

Comment: @Flyk Not so bad idea, afterall 30 also has some more significance when thinking in days and not in weeks.

Comment: I shall make the amendment with citations (actually I don't remember who posted the answer)

Comment: @Flyk Wut? Which amendment? Which answer? Which citation? Where am I?

Comment: [This](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1672/5603)... you'd still need to update the help page, obviously.