# New chatroom for site moderation and maintenance

Tags: discussion, chat, editing, moderation

As some of you might already have noticed, there is a new general chatroom associated with this site called [Movies & TV Moderation and Maintenance](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40705). The primary purpose of this room is to serve as a **meeting place and news feed for all the users interested and engaged in the moderation and maintenance** of this site.

This does *not* mean we cannot discuss whatever important site maintenance topics we want in our main chatroom, [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888). It is still a natural place to talk about the site. The new chatroom was primarily created to serve as a feed for various interesting questions and news items related to maintaining the site, feeds that would suffocate the main chatroom if they were all routed there. But maybe in the future it can as well serve for more important maintenance discussions that would otherwise clog the main chatroom.

Currently there is multitude of various different feeds served into the room:

- **New meta questions:** Those are naturally always interesting for everyone inclined on moderating the site.
- **Smoke Detector:** A site-filtered feed of the [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/README.md) bot that posts all kinds of suspicious possible spam or offensive posts. They *might* require corresponding flags or maybe just edits.
- **Hot Network Questions:** A site-filtered feed of all new questions that make it under the top 30 [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/). Those questions sometimes require special attention, be it to keep discussions in line or to edit them into the best shape possible, since they're practically the signboard of our site towards the rest of SE. Unfortunately it can only track the top 30 HNQs currently, a problem [already adressed on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277719/162011).
- **Franchise questions lacking tags:** Two feeds of new (or recently active) questions that either have a franchise tag (like [star-wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars)) but no individual work tag (like [the-phantom-menace](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-menace)) or vice versa. Those *might* require additional tags and are thus good to know for any users more experienced in the site's tagging rules. The list of work tags and their corresponding franchise tags is currently maintained manually by me as a Google Spreadsheet, but could in the future be shared with other users interested in managing it.
- **Identification questions lacking a tag:** A feed posting questions that have a genre tag (like [horror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)) but no identification tag (like [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie)). Those *might* need an ID tag. The list of genre tags is also maintained manually as a Google Spreadsheet.

Of course, those feeds are all just hints, there doesn't necessarily have to be a problem with a Hot Network Question, neither does every genre-tagged question have to be an ID question, nor is every post identified by the Smoke Detector necessarily spam. So still handle those posts responsibly.

So if you're **interested in maintaining and moderating the site and its posts, feel free to pay that chatroom a regular visit**. The volume of stuff in there should be rather low anyway, especially since the community already does quite a good job at maintaining the site. And if you have any other **suggestions about this chatroom and its purpose, feel free to share them** here.

Comment: for what it's worth, I am 100% on board with The Screaming Room

Comment: @cde I considered a more joking name, but given the very specific purpose and the the rather serious nature, I wasn't sure if that only confuses people, especially outside users who might completely mistake its purpose or even inside users who still don't know what it's good for. I even disregarded something like "Movies & TV Review" because "movie review" has quite a different meaning in general. But anyway, feel free to suggest that in an answer if you deem it a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I, for one, welcome our new chatroom. (Obviously, since I [proposed the idea myself](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/should-we-encourage-swifter-deletion-of-bad-id-questions?cb=1) a few weeks ago.)

One fairly minor suggestion: **it should have a shorter, snappier name.**

"Movies & TV Moderation and Maintenance" is a hell of a mouthful (reminiscent of the rather sillily lengthily named [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)). Including "Movies & TV" in the room name is superfluous, since the room already has M&TV colours and the only place people are going to see it in the sidebar is on the M&TV or M&TV meta sites. And "moderation" and "maintenance" are both long words. If you want to popularise, you need a snappy catchphrase!

If you don't want to invoke any humour, how about something like **"Site Cleanup Room"** or **"Site Maintenance"**?

Or, as others have proposed, perhaps **"The Screaming Room"** or **"The Production Room"** or **"The Board Room"**?

Comment: Well, I actually had that idea *before* you proposed it, though. ;-)

Comment: Or *The Cutting Floor/Room*.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The cutting floor doesn't make sense without room... It's generally "The Cutting Room Floor"...

Comment: @Catija Indeed.

Comment: What about "Censor Board".

Answer (score -1):

Why don't we merge it with [The Screening Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room)?

There is nearly no activity in that room and those interesting bots don't even get the response they deserve.

Comment: The problem with that (and the reason it is a separate room) is that those bots would just suffocate the main chat room. Instead of merging them into it, I'd rather just drop the bots maybe.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a "miscellaneous" room now, too.  I'm not sure what that's about.  I think that the screening room pretty much covers all topics.