# Why questions get deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Some examples

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59908/alien-movie-where-alien-needs-mens-orgasms-to-live/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49295/movie-with-young-girl-who-draws-visions-plays-in-japan-asia-released-4-ye/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47751/movie-where-guy-loves-a-girl-who-is-revealed-to-be-his-sister/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47731/whats-the-name-of-this-horror-sci-fi-movie/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46994/cannibalism-in-russian-famine-movie-little-boys-sister-gets-eaten/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49016/tv-series-about-mystery-crime-solving-duo/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50161/father-nearly-kills-little-girl-later-she-runs-away-with-her-boyfriend-and-is-t

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52173/please-identify-this-movie-action/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64895/id-movie-girl-with-bad-teeth-and-her-nerd-male-best-friend/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61733/cant-find-a-film-about-brother-and-sister-after-parents-death/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59429/help-identify-this-chick-flick/

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57082/movie-about-two-news-reporters-figuring-out-a-murder-but-one-of-them-is-actually/

and more

Comment: Is there additional informaton that you could add so we kow what you are on about?

Comment: @natural I asked why a lot of questions (identify this movie questions in particular) get deleted later on. I have no way of knowing what those questions except the ones I answered so I posted some of them. (You can read the answer and comments below for more details!)

Answer (score 8):

Those are all questions that have been **closed for more than 9 days without any improvements** into reopenability. They are thus eligible for cleanup as, being off-topic, they **don't provide any further benefit to the site** and its community, especially since they all have a score of 0 or less. Leaving closed and downvoted questions around sets a bad example for future users replicating behaviour that the community deemed inappropriate.

The single only question in that list that has not been closed is [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50161/49), which was subject to our existing policy of **deleting ID questions that have been inactive for more than a month and did not receive any positively voted or accepted answers**, as explained in the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well, 6 of those questions have been closed by you without any other close votes (as far as I know), ~ 4 questions OP confirmed it's the right answer, most of the answers were upvoted. and the question you mentioned is an upvoted question with a confirmed anwser (not accepted which happens a lot unfortunately) so why and how it'll remain active forever?!

Comment: @madmada Question upvotes don't matter for the inactivity policy, as [explained on meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1671/49). Neither do upvoted answers magically make questions on-topic, nor does anywerability equal question quality, as repeatedly explained.

Comment: I don't get it! If rule is to delete "any identification question inactive for 30 days and without any upvoted or accepted answers." then why the questions with upvoted answers got deleted?

Comment: @madmada Because those questions have all been ***closed***. There's no benefit to an obviously off-topic and downvoted question staying around. The inactivity policy only applies to the single question from that list that *hasn't* been closed. Those are two different things, as elaborated [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1417/49).

Comment: Is there is something in the rules say that? And again, you decided to close half of them yourself!

Comment: @madmada Say what? That downvoted off-topic questions have no value to the site? That's not a rule, that's common sense. And I closed to questions in accordance with the site's standards for identification questions.

Comment: According to you. And it doesn't make sense that someone can put a question off-topic, close it then delete all by himself without something in the rules saying that he can!

Comment: @madmada There is something in the rules saying that I can, specifically the fact *that* I can. Moderators can close questions single-handedly in clear-cut cases for the simple reason that they are supposed to know how the site works and what questions it deems appropriate. The same goes for the deletion ability. I'm sorry *you* don't agree that a bad question isn't improved by having answers, but that's just not how SE works.

Comment: I think it should be up to the community to decide what's a bad question and what's not.

Comment: @madmada Judging by the responses to [posts like this](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2292/49) the community seems to be in agreement that those posts need proper maintenance. Neither did our guidelines for ID questions and closing bad ID questions (as elaborated in the help center) come out of *thin air* rather than from the community. You are right, I'm *not* the community, but neither are *you*, we *all* are. And I'm acting on what *we* decided in the past.

Comment: I meant the community decide by "close votes" and not being deleted by one person especially when the rules didn't state that it should be deleted. Also, I didn't mean to sound rude, I'm just disagreeing with some of your points wholeheartedly!

Comment: I know, I didn't *think* you sound rude either, don't worry. ;-)

Comment: Just making sure I wasn't. It's not my first language so sometimes I can't really tell!